# Operator precedence in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, operators

This is a very old question, however, today I read on [this](https://cs50.harvard.edu/resources/cppreference.com/operator_precedence.html) and the article emphasizes that: "It is important to note that there is no specified precedence for the operation of changing a variable into a value". Here is an example given in the article to demonstrate the claim:

```
float x, result;
x = 1;
result = x / ++x;
```

"Depending on which compiler you are using, the variable result can either be 1.0 or 0.5" -->> I don't understand clearly this. Any comments?

Comment: It's nothing to do with operator precedence, but with sequencing. The two uses of `x`, one of which modifies it, aren't sequenced. That gives undefined behaviour, so anything might happen.

Comment: What that page meant to say was that operator precedence does not affect *order of evaluation*; that is, given an expression like `a + b * c`, the subexpressions `a`, `b`, and `c` may be evaluated *in any order*. `b * c` must be evaluated before the result can be added to `a`, but that doesn't mean `b` and `c` must be evaluted before `a`.  This is why expressions like `x / ++x` are problematic, because it's not guaranteed that `x` will be evaluated before `++x` or vice versa.  Also, it's not guaranteed that the *side effect* of the `++` operator will be applied immediately after evaluation.